# How to extract a string from an array powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to extract a string from the following $parse.

```
 $parse = select-string -path .\xxx.log "Error" -allmatches –simplematch -context 1
```

Example of string contain:

```
 Start : Error : billing 1150116682 not found - exit. Source : /mnt/xxx/roo/foo/aaa/115565841_yyyyy.pdf
===================================================================================================================================================
```

I need extract only Source : /mnt/xxx/roo/foo/aaa/115565841_yyyyy

how can I do it ?

thx

Comment: You can use substring for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `-SimpleMatch` because that prevents use of a regular expression, which we can use to extract the needed substring. Here is an example:

```
$s = "Start : Error : billing 1150116682 not found - exit. Source : /mnt/xxx/roo/foo/aaa/115565841_yyyyy.pdf"
$s | Select-String "Error : .* Source : (.*)" | ForEach-Object {
  $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value -replace '\.pdf$', ''
}
```

The above outputs the string `/mnt/xxx/roo/foo/aaa/115565841_yyyyy`.

Comment: exclude the `.pdf`

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I also found in this property what I also look for. All I have to do is to treat her <pre> $parses |foreach {
 $_.context.Postcontext
} </pre>

Comment: Thanks! I had to list the versions from a path.
`$listOfInstalledVersions = Get-ChildItem $path |  Select-Object Name | Select-String "funky\.foo-(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)" | ForEach-Object {
  $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
 }
`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a string split like this:

`$array = $parse.split(':')
 $lastItem = $array[-1]`

And then get the item you want from the list. Assuming you know where what you need is.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.